# SSH disconnecting from rapsberry pi when running code

Tags: python, ssh, raspberry-pi

i have a program running on an Rpi 4B that moves a webcam to centre my face in the stream. when i run the code, it works for around 10 - 20s before my raspberry pi disconnects from ssh. the pi doesnt crash, or short circuit anywhere, and this didnt happen yesterday with the code. i havent changed anything on the raspberry pi.
for context, i connect to my pi via ssh to run the code on it and it works fine, and can idle for a long time, until the code is run, and then the pi disconnects from my computer.
the error message that occurs on my computers terminal:
`client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset`
this is the code in question:

```
import os
from math import floor
from gpiozero import AngularServo

SERVO_X = AngularServo(18, min_angle=-90, max_angle=90)
SERVO_Y = AngularServo(15, min_angle=-90,max_angle=90)
VIDEOCENTREX = 640
VIDEOCENTREY = 360

VIDEO_CAPTURE = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
CASCADE_PATH = "FACE_DETECTION.xml"
FACE_CASCADE = cv2.CascadeClassifier(CASCADE_PATH)
##CENTRE THE SERVOS
SERVO_X.angle = 0
SERVO_Y.angle = 0
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = VIDEO_CAPTURE.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = FACE_CASCADE.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleFactor=1.1,minNeighbors=5,minSize=(30, 30))
    print(len(faces))
    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        centre_x = floor(x+(w/2))
        centre_y = floor(y+(h/2))
        print(centre_x, centre_y)
        

    if len(faces) == 1:
        if centre_x > VIDEOCENTREX:
            SERVO_X.angle += -1
            print("X - 1")
        elif centre_x < VIDEOCENTREX:
            SERVO_X.angle += 1
            print("X +1")
        if centre_y > VIDEOCENTREY:
            SERVO_Y.angle += -1
            print("y - 1")
        elif centre_y < VIDEOCENTREY:
            SERVO_Y.angle += 1
            print("Y + 1")
        
        


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
VIDEO_CAPTURE.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

(rpi 4b running on 32bit raspbian os lite, with a 32gb sd card)
(my pc running on windows 10)

Comment: Seems like a Raspberry pi issue to me

Comment: You can use `tmux`, `screen`, or similar to set up a long-lived local session that doesn't require SSH.

Comment: That said, do be sure you're checking `dmesg` for logs indicating OOM killer activity or hardware bugs being logged by drivers -- running your raspberry pi out of RAM is an easy way to make it start killing processes. I could also conceive of something like a power supply issue causing the networking to get flaky when under heavy CPU load; lots of weird things can happen when you push embedded hardware hard.

Comment: In general, you need more information than a description of a symptom that could be caused by any number of things to have a narrow, specific question as our topicality rules require.